# ASPX page to open excel file in local c drive - permission error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, oledb

I have this sub in ASPX page. code behind is VB.net.
This sub will open an excel file and I would like to fill a datatable. 
but I am getting a permission error. how can I solve this? 
Thank you

The error I get is

> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: The Microsoft
>   Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is
>   already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to
>   view and write its data.

```
Private Sub ProcessFile(sFileName As String)

    Dim sConnectionString As String
    sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sFileName & ";Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO"""

    Dim OLEConn As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)
    Dim sSQL As String
    sSQL = "Select * from [Sheet1$]"
    Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, OLEConn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim OLEAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    OLEAdapter.Fill(dt)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try giving Network Services account Read permission to the folder where the file is located

Comment: Alternatively put the file in the root of the web directory and see if it can open the file. If it can then you know you need to set folder permissions.